# String with 2 apostrophes - remove one of the apostrophes from the string

Tags: string, vb.net

So I have a a little issue....

I have a string that looks like this...

```
O''Neil
```

is there a way for me to remove one of the apostrophes? Basically I'd like to convert it back to

```
O'Neil
```

Comment: You do not need to alter the data if you use parameters

Comment: @Plutonix - i know but we don't use params :(

Comment: ...but this is just one of the 30 or 40 reasons why you should.

Comment: @Plutonix.......but believe me, if I'm writing my own app, parameters are going to be used. this is me fixing an apostrophe issues with users screaming at me to do it asap

Comment: Best to use params as suggested; but to answer your question, use String.Replace()... like "O''Neil".Replace("''", "'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can help you: 
**Note** - I left the Error handling to you.

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()

        Dim data As String = "O''Neil"

        Dim in1 As Integer = data.IndexOf("'"C) ' get the index of first quote
        Dim in2 As Integer = data.IndexOf("'"C, in1 + 1)  ' get the index of second     
        Dim result As String = data.Remove(in2, 1)  ' remove the second quote

        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: This code will throw an exception if there aren't two single-quotes, and also there's already a built in .net function String.Replace() that combines that whole sub's logic into a single call that won't throw an exception if 2 single-quotes aren't found. Why reinvent the wheel?